# How can I get a position (a 3d coordinate) on a curve via curve length via python?

Tags: python

If there is a curve selected, I want to get the 3d position on the curve via the percentage.
For example:
get the 3d postion on the curve at 1/5 of the curve length.
get the 3d postion on the curve at 2/5 of the curve length.

Comment: what is the type of the curve in [‘RESOLUTION’, ‘SEGMENTS’, ‘SPLINE’]?

Comment: bezier curve. I want to get uniform positions along curve, then put mesh vertices to the positions. The 3d coordinates should be in global space.

Answer (score 1):

##### Get position of n% length of curve

```
import bpy

# create curve and empty
bpy.ops.curve.primitive_bezier_curve_add(enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(2, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
curve = bpy.context.object
curve.data.resolution_u = 64
bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='PLAIN_AXES', align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
empty = bpy.context.object

# make constraint
bpy.ops.object.constraint_add(type='FOLLOW_PATH')
empty.constraints["Follow Path"].target = curve
bpy.ops.constraint.followpath_path_animate(constraint="Follow Path", owner='OBJECT')
curve.data.path_duration = 100

# get position of 50% length
curve.data.eval_time = 50
bpy.context.view_layer.update()
matrix = empty.matrix_local
print(matrix[0][3], matrix[1][3], matrix[2][3])
```

Comment: awesome! It works well. But is there no direct API to access the positions on curve?

Comment: It seems not. But you can access `splines[0].bezier_points` to get the control points to calculate the position, but the math is not easy.